# How to create single instance for multiple endpopints in wcf

Tags: wcf, in-memory

**Scenario**:
I have single instance type of wcf service. which keep data in memory.
Clients call the service and get data without hitting the db. 
Wcf Service is host in windows service.
In windows service i have used timer, on the bases of which wcf service hit the database and refresh the data.

Now problem is that when call of refresh take place, request of data client impacted and got time out.

Now i have tried two endpoints. One for consumer and second for refresh.
Both working well, but even refresh endpoint refresh the data. consumer endpoint gives old data whether refresh endpoint showing correct data.

Code Example

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    List<string> Name;
    public Service1()
    {
        Name = new List<string>();
        CollectData1();
    }

    public List<string> CollectData()
    {
        CollectData1();
        return Name;
    }

    public List<string> CollectData1()
    {
        List<string> _name = new List<string>();
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select name from test";
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
                sqlConnection1.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string a = Convert.ToString(reader[0]);
                            _name.Add(a);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Name = _name;
        return Name;
    }

    public List<string> GetData()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use a static variable: **static List<string> Name**